# Excel VBA AppActivate opens Edge in Windows File Explorer

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-edge, microsoft-file-explorer

I have a VBA code that calls a window "View Report" into focus in order to copy all data from that page and paste in into Excel.

```
        AppActivate "View Report", True
        Application.SendKeys "^a^c", True
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))
        AppActivate "Export Report"
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:2"))
```

However if the webpage is open Edge, instead of activating Edge, it opens File Explorer. Even though file Explorer wasn't running, the Edge webpage is showing as a File Explorer instance instead. (I'm not sure if I said that correct, but what I mean is if I right click and close "File Explorer", it closes both Windows file explorer and Edge. Also, if I mouse over the File Explorer icon, it shows the preview of the webpage) I'm confused as this just started happening after the recent Windows 10 S0H2 Update and happens across multiple machines. If the "View Report" webpage is open in Chrome instead, the code works fine and there are no issues. Anyone have any idea what could cause this or what I can do to fix it? Other than use Chrome all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I tested it and got the same issue.

Therefore, the key point is what changes have been made to the AppActivate API in windows 20H2, which caused the activate Edge to not work.

Try to send feedback to the relevant team, just press Shift + Alt + I in Edge.